# Why does creating sbt project in IntelliJ IDEA cause "Permission Denied"?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

When creating a sbt project using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4 with the Scala plugin 0.41.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.4, the following error has occurred:

> [warn] problem while downloading module descriptor:
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.11/2.2.1/scalatest_2.11-2.2.1.pom:
>   /Users/.../.ivy2/cache/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.11/ivy-2.2.1.xml.original.part
>   (Permission denied) (384ms)

which prevents refreshing project dependencies.

What could be the issue and a solution?

Comment: Could it be that you've been running two sbt sessions and they were accessing the same file simultaneously? It could also be a real permission denied issue so check the permissions of the file path and every directory.

Comment: I have only one sbt session. Checking the file access permissions didn't help! The workaround is to run idea as a sudo command.

Comment: Sudo for IDEA is unacceptable. Let's strive for something better. What user do you run IDEA under? What are the permissions for the .ivy2 directory? I think you once ran sbt/activator/IDEA using sudo and that messed up the local repo's permission. Could you rename .ivy2 directory and start over a sbt session?

Comment: The problem was that the .ivy cache was created by typesafe activator which was run as a sudo command. So the owner of .ivy cache files was root. Changing the owner to current user, solved the problem. Thank you for the hints, please post an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you once ran sbt/activator/IDEA using `sudo` that messed up the local repo's permissions that made `root` the owner.

Check the permissions of `~/.sbt` and `~/.ivy2` directories that should allow the current user to read and write files to the directories.

Comment: Im having this issue too, but not with IDEA, I ran sudo in my project directory and now its giving Permission errors. .sbt and .ivy2 look ok permission wise, is there some other place to check

Comment: If you have changed build.sbt to listen on port 80, remove that line. IntelliJ still thinks app wants to run on 80.

Comment: I don't have `~/.sbt`

Comment: @techkuz What's the OS? What's the exact error message?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski ubuntu 16.04, I have`~/.sbt/` folder but no such file. Though I was able to fix my error another way, by running `IDEA` manually `./idea.sh` under current user.

Comment: Ouch. It's only now when I figured out what you meant by _"I don't have ~/.sbt"_ You thought it should be a file, but actually I meant a directory. Fixed the answer to include "directories". Does this read better?